# Trying to make a dialog window remember its last position

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a simple dialogue window in C#, and want to remember where it is placed so that I can open another in the same place later (during the same application run, so no need for config files etc). I can easily save the Location (a Point) or the Bounds (a Rectangle), but on creating another form, calling `form.ShowDialog()` resets both:

```
 Form form= new Form();   

 form.Location = ptSavedLocation;
 //now form.Location is correct

 form.ShowDialog();
 //now form.Location is default again, and form is displayed where I don't want it.
```

How can I get the form to respect its Location (or Bounds, or any other appropriate property / setter) ?   Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to check whether the saved location is still within the visible area of the *current* display. This can be a pain for users e.g. when working with roaming profiles or remote desktop and different screen resolutions (such as home office)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the forms start position to Manual

eg.

```
 Form form= new Form();   

 form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

 form.Location = ptSavedLocation;
 //now form.Location is correct

 form.ShowDialog();
 //now form.Location is default again, and form is displayed where I don't want it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the forms StartPosition property to Manual